# How to get luminance of an HDR image

Tags: python, opencv, hdr

I am currently working on a project where I have a bunch of HDR images and I need to get the median luminance of each image and plot them.

I am trying using **opencv** but I am unable to find a function or way to get the median luminance of an image. Is there any way to do it? I am sure there should be some ways but I am just can't see to find it.

Comment: convert to LAB colorspace and extract the L (luminance) channel. Then get the average (mean) of the luminance channel or the median of the luminance.  See cv2.cvtColor() to change color spaces and see cv2.mean() to get the average or np.median() for the median.

Comment: @fmw42 can you please share a code example? I am finding it hard to get it work, Thanks in advance

Comment: The term "Luminance" is not well defined. Please do some research and define "Luminance". The term "HDR images" is not well defined, please do some research and define the standard and the format of the HDR images. Assuming you can't post an HDR sample image, consider posting a 10x10x3 NumPy array that represents the content of a raw HDR image (explain what the sample represents).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the issue thanks to the comment of @fmw42. Writing his comment as an answer so that it helps others.

@fmw42 commented -

> convert to LAB colorspace and extract the L (luminance) channel. Then
> get the average (mean) of the luminance channel or the median of the
> luminance. See cv2.cvtColor() to change color spaces and see
> cv2.mean() to get the average or np.median() for the median.